# Gigya - Mobile sdks - new user detection

Tags: android, ios, mobile, gigya

Given the data provided at `onLogin` event and considering that I am using RaaS and screenSets. 
How can I determine if the user is new (I mean just registered) or not?

Note: I'm aware of the property `newUser` returned, but the documentation says that it does not work with tfa users and I just confirmed that it doesn't work either with email/password accounts which requires email verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, both TFA and email verification create the user in the database prior to them verifying, so the newUser flag is always false by the time the registration is finalized. Depending upon your implementation, you can use the accountCreated webhook to track when new users are created in the database, or accountRegistered webhook if you only want to track fully registered new users.

https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Webhooks

Comment: So, from mobile sdk point of view there is no way of knowing this?

Comment: @FernandoJascovich Can you descibe a little what you are trying to do? Do you need to know this when the user is actually finalized, or are you just trying to determine their status at every login?

Comment: I need to know if, at the event onLogin (fired by some screenset) the recently logged in user is new or not. I need to determine if every logged in user is the result of one registration process or login.

Comment: Ok, there is currently no out-of-the-box solution, however, there may be a work around. You can create a field in the site's data schema like numLogins and you can add a few lines of JS to the global Conf object so every time the onLogin event is fired it will increment (or simply a boolean that is true after the first login). Not perfect, and obviously will show all users as 0 the first time they login after it is implemented (if the app is already live). Other than that, you can always add a FR via the Support tab of the Gigya console.